# get field value in dynamic form in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I created dynamic form using antd library
and in this dynamic form there is 2 input fields
input type number & input type text
I want to get the value of input type number field & check if it equals to one make
other text field is disabled
how can I make this using antd
this is the code I've tried but it doesn't work as I want
https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-antd4131-forked-l3ml5?file=/index.js